# Angular show Success Message of Submit in other Route

Tags: json, angular, post, request

I do a http post with a header. After this Post I navigate to a List of Customers and want to show SuccesMessage that Entry is included. How can I display message on other route?
Here is my Code:

```
postData({
  let url = "api.url"
  var header = new HttpHeaders .... // etc.
  this.http.post(url, { company: this.form.value.company }, { headers (header)}).toPromise().then((data: any) => { console.group(data) })
```

After post route to page an show message:

```
this.router.navigate(['customer']);
this.showMsg = true;
```

Here is my html

```
<div *ngIf="showMsg">Success</div>
```

But no success message is shown. Why? And what do I have to do? Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a data sharing entity such as a service. For example you could have a service containing this:

```
  private msgSubject: BehaviorSubject<void> = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0);
  public msg$: Observable<void> = this.msgSubject.asObservable();
  
  showMsg(): void {
     this.msgSubject.next();
  }
```

then in the component you navigate to after redirection you just have to inject the service and then subscribe to the observable `msg$`:

```
this.msgService.msg$.subscribe(() => (this.showMsg = true));
```

You will also need to call the `showMsg` method of the service once your post is successful.

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you very much! I tried code, but I have some trouble. Can you send me little more help? At the moment I created Service name "friends.service.ts" . How do I get BehaviorSubject ? Would be great if you could send me some more details of use.

Comment: in both component, the one before routing and the component you navigate to you will inject the service in the constructor: private friendsService: FriendsService. Then on the ngOnInit of the component you navigate to you subscribe to the observable msg$. On the component where you post, where you have the router.navigate you add this.friendsService.showMsg(). this will trigger the subscribe and show the message on your second component